# Scrape specific remote HTML with just Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I'm designing a Javascript API, and I need it to scrape the content of specific remote HTML pages. For example, I need to tell it to get the InnerHTML of the element with the ID "greeting" and send it back to me as a string. Is this possible to do with just JS? If not, do I need to use Node.js or PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YQL might be just what you need!

See https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

It lets you grab non local data via a JSONP interface. What this means is you will be able to scrape remote HTML with just client side javascript.

[Here is an example](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#yql_html_scraper) I took from yahoo's website

```
<b>Stories: </b> <input type='text' size='15' id='story' value='world'/><br/><br/>
<button id='get_stories'>Get Stories</button>
<div id='results'></div>
<script src="https://yui-s.yahooapis.com/3.8.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
<script>
// Calls YQL Web service, parses results, and outputs results
YUI().use('node', 'event', 'yql', function(Y) {
  Y.one("#get_stories").on('click',function() {
    var stories = "<div><ul>";
    var story = Y.one('#story').get('value') || 'world';
    var news_url = "http://news.yahoo.com/";
    var yql_query = "select * from html where url='" + news_url + story + "'";
    yql_query += " and xpath='//div[@class=\"content\"]//div[@class=\"txt\"]/p'";
    Y.YQL(yql_query, function(response) {
      if(response.query.results){
        var no_stories = response.query.results.p.length;
        var paras = response.query.results.p;
        paras.forEach(function(node,index) {
          if (node.hasOwnProperty('a') && node.hasOwnProperty('content')) {
            stories += "<li><a href='" + news_url + node.a.href + "' title='" + node.a.title + "'>" + node.content + "</a></li>";
          }
       });
      } else{
        stories += "Sorry, could not find any headlines for the category " + story + ". Please try another one.";
      }
      stories += "</ul></div>";
      Y.one('#results').append(stories);
      stories = "";
    });
  }); 
});       
</script>
```

Comment: I'm very new to JS. Is there any way you could simplify that down to something like: "Look at this page; Find this element; Get the content; var content = theContent;"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you've tried using the selenium library to help you get the information you need?

It's used mostly for doing UI automation validations; if you're just using locally it can help you get information you need:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs